# Generating Realistic Reticulated Foam Material

Tags: materials

Any tips for creating a realistic [reticulated foam](https://www.gbfoam.co.uk/foam-market-sectors-manufacturer/reticulated-foam/) material or can somebody point me in the right direction of any tutorials. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/how-to-create-porous-material/43780#43780

Comment: or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124126/auxetic-foam-cell-structure/124298#124298