# any ideas for a foamy material

Tags: materials

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this foamy material?

Comment: Hi what have you tried? Please [edit] your question and show your work. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [how to create porous material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/how-to-create-porous-material/43780#43780) and  [foam cell structure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124126/auxetic-foam-cell-structure/124298#124298) and [give this mesh a uniform thickness on all the tubes and unions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80296/give-this-mesh-a-uniform-thickness-on-all-the-tubes-and-unions?)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like this. It's just a Noise Texture mixed with a Voronai Texture to make the bumpy surface, with another (scaled up) Noise Texture passed through a ColorRamp to provide the value for both the BaseColor and Metallic to make the "shiny white bits".

[image]