# Blender 2.8 - where is Multiple Importance Sampling?

Tags: world

I am working on  my render and I have an hdr word background, I am trying to activate Multiple Importance Sampling like in previous Blender and I can't find it. Anyone knows where is it or what changed? thanks alot in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It is under the *Properties Window > World Settings > Surface* change *Sampling* from *Auto* to *Manual*.

Multiple importance sampling is only available for volumes, under *Volume > Sampling* change from *Equiangular* to *Multiple Importance*.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, yes but it doesn't have the check box for " Multiple Importance Sampling" does it comes activated by default? what has changed? is not clear

Comment: Before you only had the checkbox option, now you have the "Distance", "Equiangular" and "Multiple Importance" options.

Comment: thanks a lot guys! now I have to learn what the new options do.
 is there any documentation on this?
cheers!

Comment: Here is the Blender 2.80 Reference Manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/